# Getting blank value in ng-options angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<select 
  get-sport
  name="sportId"
  id="sportId"
  ng-model="sm.sport_id"
  ng-change="changeSport()"
  ng-options="sport.sport_id as sport.name for sport in sports track by sport.sport_id"
  ng-required="true">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Sport--</option>
</select>

return {
        scope : true,
        link : function (scope) {

            scope.spinning = true;
            $http.get('v1/sport')
                .success(success)
                .error(error);

            function success(data){
                scope.sports = data.data;
                scope.spinning = false;
            }

            function error(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }

        }
    };
```

In my console `Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]`

Object having name : cricket, sport_id : '1'

Into my sm.sport_id getting value 3 it should be equal to name : football, sport_id : 3 but by default it is selecting blank value i don't understand why please guide thanks a ton in advance

Comment: please add one json example of your array

Comment: Object { sport_id: "1", name: "Cricket" }
Object { sport_id: "2", name: "Hockey" }
Object { sport_id: "1", name: "Football" }

Comment: please refer this blogpost https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281793/why-angular-ng-options-with-track-by-cant-selected-by-id)

"you just can't combine value as label for collection with track by. You have to pick the one or the other.".

```
<select ng-model="sport" ng-options="sport as sport.name for sport in sports track by sport.id">
```

an in this case you can only get the selected sport as your selected option not the id of that

```
$scope.sports = [{id: 1, name: 'Cricket'}, {id: 2, name: 'Hockey'}, {id: 3, name: 'Football'}]
    $scope.sport = $scope.sports[0];
```

Comment: why do i change model name. I need to use the same model name

Comment: you can USE YOUR MODEL NAME,I JUST USE DIFFRENT MODEL NAME IN MY TRYS

Comment: the important thing is how to use track by in ng option

Comment: can you send me what do you use ?

Comment: Actually its getting blank value by default into the dropdown. I don't know why same above code i used

Comment: do you change sport _id to sport in ng-options="sport.sport_id as sport.name for sport in sports track by sport.sport_id"

Comment: please replace this code to your ng-option
   <select 
  get-sport
  name="sportId"
  id="sportId"
  ng-model="sm.sport_id"
  ng-change="changeSport()"
  ng-options="sport as sport.name for sport in sports track by sport.id"
  ng-required="true">
  <option value="" ng-if="hideOption" selected="selected">-- Select Sport--</option>

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove blank in option and dont initialize value for it . Add ng-if in option .

```
<select 
  get-sport
  name="sportId"
  id="sportId"
  ng-model="sm.sport_id"
  ng-change="changeSport()"
  ng-options="sport_id as sport.name for sport in sports track by sport_id"
  ng-required="true">
  <option value="" ng-if="hideOption" selected="selected">-- Select Sport--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I do so it will take first value doesn't take model value

Comment: @Amy show your model value please . And this code doesn't take value

Comment: <select 
                  get-sport
                  name="sportId"
                  id="sportId"
                  ng-model="team.sport_id"
                  ng-change="changeSport()"
                  ng-options="sport.sport_id as sport.name for sport in sports track by sport.sport_id"
                  ng-required="true">
                  <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Sport--</option>
                </select>

Comment: @Amy try add ng-if in your option

Comment: above directive i used

Comment: I did try doesn't work. I think it is not fetching the exact json match with sport.id

Answer (score 0):

I overcome this point myself the sport_id need to convert fr4om integer to string i did so it work like a charm