# AngularJS ng-options ng-model option selected by id

Tags: angularjs

Why this code doesn't work as expected? I expect China be selected in the `select` but it is empty.

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appController" class="p-2" ng-init="init()">
    <select
      name="user_country"
      class="form-control"
      ng-model="country"
      ng-options="item.id as item.title for item in countries track by item.id">
      <option value="" disabled>Select Country</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('appController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.country = 3
  $scope.countries = [
    {id: 1, title: 'US'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Japan'},
    {id: 3, title: 'China'},
    {id: 4, title: 'Russia'}
  ]
}])
```

I expect to see China rather than an empty field. Here is a CodePen example https://codepen.io/grinev/pen/YJERvz.

Comment: Just used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282707/2834876
Here an example https://codepen.io/grinev/pen/GYOPBO

Comment: Not sure why it does not work like mentioned in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Udpated the `ng-options` to

```
ng-options="item.id as item.title for item in countries">
```

**Answer**

without `track By` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/60349/)

with `track By` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7pabu54/213/)

`track by` just helps Angular internally with array sorting as far as I know. The value of the options is defined by the first argument (in your case item). If you want it to be by id then you should use `item.id as item.name for item in items`

Comment: so is your answer suggesting that `track by item.id` is breaking the code?  is that something you can explain in more detail?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: you're close, but your answer is still slightly flawed.  because of the way that `track by` works, the `ng-model` **cannot** be a primitive, it must be the object being tracked in the array.  therefore, `item.id as` and `track by item.id` are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be storing the object, not the id. So instead of `$scope.country = 3;` you need to put it after the countries array and set it to `$scope.country = $scope.countries[2];`